# Answering InquirerPy prompts in a unit test (pytest) for Continous Integration (Gitlab CI)

Tags: python, unit-testing, continuous-integration, pytest, inquirer

I have written a program that utilizes "InquirerPy" to create and validate a series of prompts for our users.
Problem is I realized that these prompts need to be unit tested in our Continuous Integration setup.

Example:

```
from InquirerPy import inquirer
def set_path():
    config_path = inquirer.filepath(default="C:\\", message="Enter path to config folder", only_directories=True).execute()
    path_dict = {"path":config_path}
    
    if not os.path.exists(config_path):
        print(config_path)
        os.makedirs(config_path)
    # add path to json
    path = os.path.join(dir_path, "path.json")
    with open(path, "w+") as f:
        json.dump(path_dict, f)
```

Now how do I pass an argument "autonomously" in a CI setup using pytest?

An example would be a unittest that reads in the path from "path.json" and checks that it is equal to the "homepath" variable. Something like this (sort of pseudo)

```
import json
def test_set_path():
    path = "C:\\config"
    set_path() <- where we somehow pass in the path variable
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        json_path = data["path"]
    assert path == json_path
```

If i write this test, how do I pass the homepath variable into the InquirerPy prompt properly?

Comment: Have you thought about mocking or monkeypatching?

Comment: Hi, no I am not familiar with those terms, but I just looked them up and they seem to be the answer.
Thanks a lot